# GCC INLINE ASSEMBLY Won't Let Me Overwrite $esp

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm writing code to temporarily use my own stack for experimentation. This worked when I used literal inline assembly. I was hardcoding the variable locations as offsets off of ebp. However, I wanted my code to work without haivng to hard code memory addresses into it, so I've been looking into GCC's EXTENDED INLINE ASSEMBLY. What I have is the following:

```
volatile intptr_t new_stack_ptr = (intptr_t) MY_STACK_POINTER;
volatile intptr_t old_stack_ptr = 0;
asm __volatile__("movl %%esp, %0\n\t"
        "movl %1, %%esp"
        : "=r"(old_stack_ptr) /* output */
        : "r"(new_stack_ptr) /* input */
        );
```

The point of this is to first save the stack pointer into the variable old_stack_ptr. Next, the stack pointer (%esp) is overwritten with the address I have saved in new_stack_ptr.

Despite this, I found that GCC was saving the %esp into old_stack_ptr, but was NOT replacing %esp with new_stack_ptr. Upon deeper inspection, I found it actually expanded my assembly and added it's own instructions, which are the following:

```
mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
mov    %esp,%eax
mov    %eax,%esp
mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp)
```

I think GCC is trying to preserve the %esp, because I don't have it explicitly declared as an "output" operand... I could be totally wrong with this...

I really wanted to use extended inline assembly to do this, because if not, it seems like I have to "hard code" the location offsets off of %ebp into the assembly, and I'd rather use the variable names like this... especially because this code needs to work on a few different systems, which seem to all offset my variables differently, so using extended inline assembly allows me to explicitly say the variable location... but I don't understand why it is doing the extra stuff and not letting me overwrite the stack pointer like it was before, ever since I started using extended assembly, it's been doing this.

I appreciate any help!!!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but maybe `-fomit-frame-pointer` (which is enabled with `-O1` and up) would eliminate the need to worry about `%ebp`.

Comment: The extra stuff is probably there because you're doing a debug (no optimisation) build and GCC does it by default to catch potential errors. Search for "GCC Stack Frame Checks" to see what options GCC provides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so the problem is gcc is allocating input and output to the same register `eax`. You want to tell gcc that you are clobbering the output before using the input, aka. "earlyclobber".

```
asm __volatile__("movl %%esp, %0\n\t"
        "movl %1, %%esp"
        : "=&r"(old_stack_ptr) /* output */
        : "r"(new_stack_ptr) /* input */
        );
```

Notice the `&` sign for the output. This should fix your code.

**Update**: alternatively, you could force input and output to be the same register and use `xchg`, like so:

```
asm __volatile__("xchg %%esp, %0\n\t"
        : "=r"(old_stack_ptr) /* output */
        : "0"(new_stack_ptr) /* input */
        );
```

Notice the `"0"` that says "*put this into the same register as argument 0*".

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I never heard of early clobber before. Excellent answer. I really appreciate it. That fixed it.

Comment: I suppose alternatively you could just use `xchg` and then force input and output to be in the same register.