# C,inline assembly - mov instruction segfaults

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack, inline-assembly

We're trying to implement some kind of "fibers" and want for each a "stack" allocated on the heap, let's say of fixed size somewhere near 2MB, for now.

```
//2MB ~ 2^21 B = 2097152 B
#define FIB_STACK_SIZE 2097152

#define reg_t uint32_t

typedef struct fiber fiber;
struct fiber{
    ...
    //fiber's stack
    reg_t esp;
    ...
};
```

During creation of a fiber, we allocate that "stack" and enqueue the created struct for later use in a ready queue.

```
void fib_create(...){
    //fiber struct itself
    f = malloc(sizeof(*f)); //f later enqueued
    ...     
    //fiber stack
    f->stack = malloc(FIB_STACK_SIZE);
    f->esp = (reg_t)f->stack;
    ...
}
```

`fib` is the struct taken from the ready queue for which we need to restore the context.

Obviously, we first need to restore the stack pointer s.th. we can restore everything else:

```
void fib_resume(){
    //assumes `fib' holds fiber to resume execution

    //restore stack pointers
    __asm__(
        "movl %0, %%esp;"
        :
        :"rm"(fib->esp)
        );

    ...
}
```

However, that move instruction will result in a segfault. Why? And how can we circumvent that?

Comment: You should create [mcve].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392336/gcc-inline-assembly-wont-let-me-overwrite-esp

Comment: Most likely it's not the "mov" that causes a segfault, it's the return from `fib_resume`. Does the stack contain sufficient information on it for the `fib_resume` function to work? Almost every operating system does context switching in assembler because it's pretty hard to know what the compiled C code expects to be on the stack.

Comment: @Art there is no "return from ``fib_resume`` sorry, I should have said so but ``fib_resume`` is never called but only ever jumped to.

Comment: @User1291 Then we get to the next problem. Are you aware of which direction your stack grows in? I suspect your machine is i386, so your stack grows down. I also suspect you're on linux, so the `malloc(2MB)` will explicitly `mmap` the large chunk of memory, so `f->stack` is page aligned and the page before is potentially not mapped. The first time you make a function call or use the stack otherwise will underflow into the not mapped memory.

Comment: In other words, try changing `f->esp = (reg_t)f->stack;` to `f->esp = (reg_t)f->stack + FIB_STACK_SIZE;` and see what happens.

Comment: @Art Of course, such a stupid error ... thank you. Do you want to elaborate so I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: @User1291 Sure, will write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On i386 (which is pretty apparent from the inline assembler) the stack grows down. That means towards lower addresses, so function calls will decrement the stack address.

This means that when we're allocating a stack for a thread/process/etc. the normal way of doing it is to point the stack pointer register at the end of the allocated memory.

In your case this should be:

```
f->esp = (reg_t)f->stack + FIB_STACK_SIZE;
```

I'm still not sure if it's a good idea to do this with inline assembler in a C function rather than writing the function completely in assembler, but this should resolve the immediate problem.